# Цвет: анилиновый или кислотный?

Tags: употребление-слов

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно называются цвета неестественной яркости, которые частенько сейчас используются в одежде (особенно молодежной)? Я слышала версии: анилиновые, кислотные, люминесцентные.
Спасибо.

Comment: [Люминесцентные][1] - это краски, основанные на хим. веществах, которые светятся. Таким образом, это в большей степени не свойство цвета или яркости краски, а именно свойство свечения в темноте.

Касательно анилиновых - смотря что подразумевать. Анилиновый цвет - это желтоватый. Т.е. не такой насыщенный и яркий про какой Вы говорите. С другой стороны, на базе анилина сделано очень много разных красителей совершенно разных цветов.

[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8

Comment: "ядовитый цвет", или уж как у классиков: "Голова ее была в чепце интенсивно абрикосового цвета"

Answer (score 1):

Кислотность  по  отношению  к  такой  манере  одеваться  -  метафора.  Как  нечто  резкое,  раздражающее.  Я  слышал  выражение -  кислота  уже  не  в  моде.

Answer (score 0):

Мне чаще всего встречался эпитет "кислотный". Например, "вот прошла девушка в кислотно-оранжевой майке". Однако в этом контексте также популярен и эпитет "неоновый", например "на витрине стоят неоново-розовые туфли". разумеется, неон здесь - не сам газ, а свойственная, скажем, неоновым вывескам "кричащая" яркость.